# Daily import into Heroku hosted Postgres database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I'm in the process of porting over a MySQL database to a Heroku hosted, dedicated PostgreSQL instance. I understand how to get the initial data over to Heroku.  However, there is a daily "feed" of data from an external company that will need to be imported each day.  It is pushed up to an FTP server and it's a zip file containing several different CSV files.  Normally, I could/would just scp it over to the Postgres box and then have a cron job that does a "COPY tablename FROM path/to/file.csv" to import the data.  However, using Heroku has me a bit baffled as to the best way to do this.  Note: I've seen and reviewed the heroku dev [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/import-data-heroku-postgres) on importing data.  But, this is more of a dump file.  I'm just dealing with a daily import from a CSV file.

Does anyone do something similar to this on Heroku?  If so, can you give any advice on what's the best way.

Just a bit more info:  My application is Python/Django 1.3.3 on the Cedar stack.  And my files can be a bit large.  Some of them can be over 50K records.  So, to loop through them and use the Django ORM is probably going to be a bit slow (but, still might be the best/only solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Boot up a non-heroku EC2 instance, fetch from FTP, unzip and initiate the copy from there. By making use of the `COPY` `STDIN` option (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html) you can instruct it that the data is coming from the client connection, as opposed to from a file on the server's filesystem which you don't have access to.
2. How large is the file? It might fit in a dyno's ephemeral filesystem, so a process or one off job can download the file from the FTP server and do the whole process from within a dyno. Once the process exits, away goes the filesystem data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Most files are under 1MB, but 1 daily file is approx 110MB and growing (but slowly). What's the size limit here? Thanks again.

Comment: The limit is undetermined, but quite large. It can take the 110MB+ just fine. Additionally, you can issue a `\copy` from the dyno referencing the temporary file (on the dyno) directly, without needing to resort to the STDIN option.

Comment: That's excellent...  It will REALLY speed it up over using Django ORM.